# Difference between green and blue comments in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've seen two types of comments in eclipse. One is with green color and the other one is with blue color. What is the difference between the two? Which is used for functions and which for classes and other variables?

Comment: Just guessing that Eclipse colors blue the Javadoc-style comments

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two types of comments are, this:

```
/**
  * comment goes here (notice the extra '*' in previous line)
  */
```

and this:

```
/*
 * comment goes here (notice the extra '*' is not present in previous line)
 */
```

These two commenting style have different colors.
First one gets blue color and second one gets green color.

The first style is a Javadoc comment, which can be used to generate various documentation formats. Eclipse will use these to generate tooltips and autocomplete documentation for the documented item.

For more detail [see the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
// and /* .. */    are standard comments and show up in green color
/** ...... **/     are javadoc comments and show up in blue color
```

Docs [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Answer (score 1):

The green comments are the normal ones and the blue ones are JavaDoc comments

Answer (score 1):

I guess one is normal comments (`/* ... */`) while the other is javadoc (`/** ... */`) do denote specific class and method documentation.